# How to query all array elements in Postgres?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a simple postgres 12 DB with two columns. The first column contains a date the second a nested jsonb array. The following query nicely maps selected data of the first element to a table.

```
SELECT
date, 
stats -> 0 -> 'item_info' ->> 'field_1' AS field_a,  
stats -> 0 -> 'item_info' ->> 'field_2' AS field_b,  
stats -> 0 -> 'status' -> 'substatus' ->> 'subsubstatus' AS field_c
FROM mytable;
```

How do I fill the remainder of the table with the next elements 1..n? Or, to put it differently, how do I get all elements mapped?

Comment: Use `cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im assuming you want something like this:

```
SELECT
  date, 
  elements -> 'item_info' ->> 'field_1' AS field_a,  
  elements -> 'item_info' ->> 'field_2' AS field_b,  
  elements -> 'status' -> 'substatus' ->> 'subsubstatus' AS field_c
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(stats) AS elements;
```